# Can I run a solar tracker that uses two MG946R servo motors with a 10 W solar panel?

Tags: power-supply, arduino, servo, solar-energy

[image]

Is it possible to run a solar tracker with a 10 W panel that connects to a 5 V buck converter and two MG946R servo motors without a battery and under a clear and sunny sky?

- [MG946R](https://www.towerpro.com.tw/product/mg946r/), stall current 1.2 A
- 5 V [buck converter](https://sg.cytron.io/p-5v-2.5a-buck-converter-6.5-27vdc-input?search=dc%20converter&description=1)
- 10 W, 17.5 V, 0.58 A [solar panel](https://sg.cytron.io/p-solar-panel-18v-555ma-10w?search=solar%20panel&description=1)

If not, can you suggest solar panel specs to run it without battery? I am doing a project to run it stand-alone, without battery.

I am just wondering if the panel is able to sufficiently power the servos for a few minutes; I don't need it to run the whole day. The project demo will showcase just a few minutes (under sunny and clear sun of course). If the weather is bad, I will show a recorded video during the test.

What if I use a 6 V NiMH battery pack between the solar panel and the load, or a 6 V,  4.5 Ah SLA battery?

Comment: What will the solar panel be powering?

Comment: With some large caps, and the panel in bright sunlight it can probably run 1 of these servos. But it would be better to use a simple gear motor instead, since that will behave more predictably when the available power/voltage is low.

Comment: 1 Amp start current. Unlikely to produce useful power or work. 110 mA idle current. So NG.

Comment: How much power do you expect to get out of the panel if it isn't already pointed at the sun?

Comment: Why are you do a project with no specs expected to fail badly?

Comment: @BruceAbbott the project will just power up 2 servos for now. i got a voltage sensor with sd card adapter for data logging and esp32-cam with motion detector ready to be implented. However for now, if i could make the solar tracker run self-sufficiently, then i will add on the rest.

Comment: @DaveTweed I will just test it during a sunny and clear day. Otherwise i wont be testing it  but only be checking the values for those bad weather.

Comment: Links to component specs always a good
 Idea. Adding a small battery that is charged when panel offer not slewing would good sense. Or a supercap.  Or a suitably geared motor
 Slewing speed need not be fast

Comment: @RussellMcMahon thanks for the advice . i have added the links to the component specs

Comment: There's good chance of this working. Maximise chances by balancing the panels so that they represent as constant a load as possible in all positions. Adding weight to a panel edge or even a counterweight on an arm can help. The servo's spec shows high peak current draw but they will operate at lower current and speed - down to a point where they stall. A photo of the physical mechanical arrangement could help. I can reopen the question if it gets somewhat answerable without guessing BUT you probably have enough information by now. ie It MAY work, there are things you can do to help it work.

Comment: Adding a battery at the V panel output will make a vast improvement. | Adding as large a cap as available will help - but not a much as a battery. | You mention LDRs - please show your circuit. LDRs will definitely need some added circuitry.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon yeah, i intend to add a 6v sla battery in. Also i have added the LDR circuitry as well

Comment: I reopened this question as the OP has added substantially more information which makes the requirement good enough for good answers to be given.

Comment: curiouser - adding new relevant information for comments into the question is always a good idea - but as the question is now it's answerable.

Comment: Servo torque is about 10 kg.cm at 5V. Panel weight is 2.8 kg (see [here](https://static.cytron.io/image/catalog/products/SC-18V-10W/SC-18V-10W%20.jpg). ) If the panel is counterbalanced (easy to do with a quick lashup) then you have enough torque available to move the panel over quite a wide arc. | I don't know how you plan to track BUT one way is to mount two panels side by side with a vertical divider that shades one or other panel when off line and makes more power from the sun-most panel. You then turn servos till panels balance. 2D tracking along an arc should be adequate.

Comment: The weight of the solar panel is 0.8kg based on that picture. A 20W will usually weighs 2kg not a 10W.

Comment: "I am just wondering if the panel is able to sufficiently power the servos for a few minutes. I don't need it to run the whole day." Doesn't matter. Since you have no energy storage (like a battery or very large capacitor), only short-term requirements matter. And 5 volts times 1.2 amps (stall) is 6 watts. 2 times 6 watts is 12. Add another 10% for losses in the buck converter (if you're lucky), and you need a minimum of 13.2 watts. Of course, if you can guarantee that the servo will never stall, that's not an issue. Can you guarantee that?

Answer (score 1):

If you were to charge a small battery from the panel then you could determine when there’s enough stored energy to make an adjustment; move either the x or y servo but perhaps not both at once.  When the panel is reasonably well aligned you should be ok to make small adjustments (a few degrees) quite frequently.  If the axis of rotation is close to the middle of the panel then wind should have little effect provided that the panel is in free airflow.

Comment: yes im getting a 6v sla battery to power up the servos and other components. Sadly, i was aiming to do one without a battery but it seems to be much of a hassle than having one

Comment: Possibly you could make do with a large capacitor, if you make small movements and let the capacitor recharge before moving again, but there’s no getting away from the fact that the panel won’t generate enough to run the set is continuously, especially if the panel is off-axis.  A battery is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: thanks frog. yeah it seems that way. i am going to use a 12V battery which will be connected to a 5V buck to power the components

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you have a panel, or panel array, that pivots to track the sun.

The #1 load acting on that panel will be wind loads.  That force will act against the tracking mechanism, and will be hundreds of pounds.

That little motor won't be able to bear wind loads.

So you will need some sort of "one-way action" jackscrew or worm drive arrangement to bear those wind loads.  Depending on how you gear and lubricate the jack screw, the motor should be able to turn it.  It will take many revolutions to swing the panel around.

Your little panel should be able to make enough power to run the motor, even somewhat mis-aimed.  However, you will need external sensors to tell the motor which way to spin.

Comment: i will just be testing it  under the sun for a short period. Regarding the wind load situation, i will stop testing if it gets too windy or bad weather. Otherwise, i will try to make it run self-sufficiently without the use of a battery for now.

Comment: yes, i will be using LDRs to control its position.

Comment: A 10W panel will not generate hundreds of pounds ... maybe in hurricane conditions. If the OP is seeing such high wind loadings, consider a wind turbine instead. However a continuous rotation motor and a jackscrew is a sound suggestion anyway.

Comment: @user_1818839  Nobody puts tracking on a 10W panel, easier to use a 20W panel for $8 more. They put tracking on a 2000W array, and they use a 10W panel *to power the tracking motor*.  That's what I presume we're dealing with here.

Comment: @curiouser Yeah the problem with steppers is they only want to "seek to" 90 degree positions.  Since I gather you want finer control than merely "East", "South" and "West", you'll need *some* sort of gear reduction.  I am merely suggesting to use a "one-way-torque" kind, like a worm or jackscrew, so you aren't spending energy to hold the array against the wind. *Once you do that, your design easily scales* - it could track a MUCH larger array with no electrical changes (just gear ratio changes).  The lower gear ratio would make it rotate slower, but it has time :)

Comment: I saw a 20W 6v 3.33A solar panel. Is that able to power up the two servos? if possible, i want the system to power via the panel only.

Answer (score 0):

> im just wondering if the panel is able to sufficiently power the
> servos for a few minutes.

The MG946R draws ~2 A peak, so 2 servos could draw up to 4 A. Theoretically with a switching regulator the 0.58 A at 17.5 V that your panel puts out in full sunlight could translate to 2 A at 5 V, but practice it will be a bit less due to converter losses.

Clearly this is **not** enough to power both servos at once. If you only operate one servo at a time you might get away with it, provided you keep the panel fairly well aligned to the sun. To handle peak currents you should add large filter capacitors (eg. 1,000 μF) to the input and output of the buck converter. Symptoms of insufficient filtering include servos jittering and the Arduino glitching, resetting or not responding to commands when the supply voltage drops out during peak current demand.

Next problem is how to reduce servo loading. RC hobby servos are designed for fast movement of aircraft control surfaces or car/boat steering, not a 0.8 kg solar panel. If you connect the servos directly to the panel with enough 'throw' to track the sun over the sky they may stall out or jitter trying to fight the high inertia of the panel. Linear actuators may work better because they move slower, have more torque and lower current draw, and hold their position better when inactive.

Another option you might want to consider is simply using two fixed solar panels facing in different directions. This may be a bit more expensive, but mechanically much simpler and more reliable.

Comment: As of now, i have little time to make much changes. Are there any suggestions from you to add on to what I have currently? Is a 20W able to at least run the two servos?

thanks

Comment: Theoretically 2 panels would be enough, but only in strong sunlight with aligned panels, and only if you add smoothing capacitors (otherwise peak panel current is only ~1A, which isn't even enough for 1 servo). In a typical _practical_ application a small battery or supercapacitors would be used to handle peak operating demand. Then you have to decide what you want - maximum power during peak sunlight, or longest operating hours per day.

Comment: thanks bruce.  guess i have to get a battery. btw, i got a mg90s servo lying around. Do you think it could support my 10w solar panel which weighs about 1kg? if it does, i guess i could use it to reduce the power consumption

Comment: MG90 servo is far too small for this application. Get a battery. 12V 7Ah SLAs are cheap and have plenty of capacity. Charge it with a PWM controller like this one:- https://www.jaycar.co.nz/miniature-12v-3a-pwm-solar-charge-controller/p/MP3762

Comment: Thanks, i got myself a 12V/24V 10A  pwm controller instead with a 12V 7.2Ah sla battery. I did not know that those motors have an initial surged  in current at starting.  Also, how much current is supplied by the 12V 7.2Ah battery? Assuming at peak charged. I understand that current does not equal to ampere-hours, so i assume it can provide 7A per hour or 3.5 A in 2 hours etc

Comment: Rated capacity is based on a 20 hour discharge. If discharged faster the capacity reduces. It should deliver ~4.5A for 1 hour, 2.8A for 2 hours, 1.5A for 4 hours etc.. Remember however that the DC/DC converter boosts current by the same ratio as it reduces voltage, so 1.5A at the battery = >3A at 5V (assuming the converter is rated for >3A). The battery can produce much higher 'burst' current so the converter will limit it first. Use a converter rated for at least 4A (eg. XL4015) if you want to run both servos at once.